# Can not open eclipse because another java is installed

Tags: java, eclipse

I have recently trying to open eclipse and it is not working this error appears

```
version 1.8.0_51 of the JVM is not suitable. Version: 11 or greater
is required
```

apparently that happened because I installed Minecraft java.

Comment: Current versions of Eclipse includes a Java that is used to run Eclipse. Therefore, I wonder, whether you face this issue by using an outdated version of Eclipse. If this is the case, install the current version of Eclipse and make sure the Javas you want to use in your projects are configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: I have just downloaded eclipse a month ago and it worked